# Unable to read a file and pass into arguments

Tags: c, linux

1) I'm trying to open a file, read the mix data (ints, chars and strings) and store them into args.

1.1) so in the sample.txt is a total of 13 (excluding args[0])

2) Need to read a file from terminal "./myprog.c < sample.txt"

Heres my code and have no idea where i went wrong:

```
sample.txt:
123 213 110 90 1
hello my friend
boo bleh
a b c
```

myprog.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i = 1;
        FILE *fstin=fopen(argv[0], "r"); //open the file
        if (fstin == NULL) {
            puts("Couldn't fopen..."); 
            return -1;
        }
         //Getting all the inputs from file
        while ((fscanf(fstin, "%d", argv[i])) != EOF){
            i++;
        }

        fclose(fstin);
        for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("%d\n",argv[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: Would like if anyone could post their complete solution? Will upload unto this post and  let everyone have a review of this problem

PPS: Please excuse the poor level of coding as I am a beginner and completely new to C.

Comment: You should change main to `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name of the execute file. Input parameters start at `argv[1]`.

Comment: yes but terminal is complaining "<" is a non-executable. so how do i input files into argv[1]?

Comment: You have to compile it first to create an executable. Maybe you can read [this](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Comment: `./myprog.c sample.txt` without the `<`

Comment: I understand that you have to remove "<" but I need to input the file from the terminal.

Comment: Then you should read from `stdin`. Note that you don't need to open it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]){
    int i, argc=0;
    char **argv=NULL, data[16];
    FILE *fstin = stdin;

    if(ac == 2){
        if(NULL==(fstin = fopen(av[1], "r"))){
            puts("Couldn't fopen...");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    while (1==fscanf(fstin, "%15s", data)){
        argv = realloc(argv, (argc+1)*sizeof(char*));
        argv[argc] = malloc(strlen(data)+1);
        strcpy(argv[argc++], data);
    }
    if(ac == 2)
        fclose(fstin);

    for (i=0; i<argc; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping this n00b programmer ;  ;! if i may ask, i didn't know you could modify "main(int ac, char*av[])" so i'm guessing here you declare 2 argc and argv[]

Comment: I suggest not arbitrarily breaking with the convention to use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` only to then define `argc` and `argv` later in `main()`. This is gratuitously confusing.

Comment: @EOF what you said is true. Would it make sense if I made main(int argc, char *arg[])? then i would declare the bottom ac = 0 and char**argv[]? what are your thoughts?

Comment: @user3440810: My thoughts are that you don't really understand what `argc` and `argv` are. `argv` is an array of length `argc` of `char*`s, terminated by a null pointer. Going by your original code, you would eventually dereference the null pointer by writing to it, while writing into the argument vector of your program for no good reason. Frankly, I have no idea *what* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @EOF my ultimate objective is to read all the data file and store into variables. to much frustation, I gave up on a lot of findings scanf,fscanf and getf... so someone told me why don't you try putting the variables into args and see how it goes. with all the variables stored in args i was HOPING to manipulate them by pulling their index from argv.

Answer (score -1):

You are making mistake at 2nd point where you divert your file to other file which is wrong. Actually you need to first compile and need to make executable.

```
gcc -o my_prog ./myprog.c -Wall
```

You need to execute this program as below to read file from c program:

```
./my_prog ./sample.txt
```

As you are new to C programming first go to man pages related to file operations.

### Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   //If command line argument is not inserted then stop operation
   if (2 !=  argc) {
      printf("Invalid number of arguments : %d\n", argc);
      return -1;
   }
   int size = 0, ret = 0;
   char *data = NULL;
   FILE *fp = NULL;

   //Open file in read mode given from command line argument
   if (NULL != (fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
   {
      //Find size of file
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      size = ftell(fp);
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
      //if file is empty no need to read it.
      if (size > 0)
      {
         //Data pointer which contains file information
         data = (char *) calloc(sizeof(char), size);
         if (NULL != data)
         {
            //Read whole file in one statement
            fread(data, sizeof(char), size, fp);

            printf("File %s is readed successfully\n", argv[1]);
            printf("Data:\n");
            printf("%s\n", data);
            free(data); data = NULL;
         }
         else
         {
            perror("memory allocation failed\n");
            ret = -1;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         printf("File %s is empty\n", argv[1]);
      }
      fclose(fp); fp = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      perror("File open failed\n");
      ret = -1;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Now Test it on your setup and if any query please post comments.

Comment: Compile Error: line41 > format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' arguement format
line 60 > too many arguements for perror.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Now you can try it. I corrected both errors.

Comment: @user3440810: This code is horrifically broken in multiple ways. 1. Casting the return value of `malloc()`. 2. Using `malloc()` and `memset()` instead of `calloc()`. 3. `char c` is checked for equality with `EOF`, which is an `int` (this is why `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`). 4. Using `strcat()` to append a single, not null-terminated `char`. That's about 3 crashbugs, plus bad style. Furthermore, to get the contents of a file into memory, use `mmap()`. Don't seek through the file to find its length, use `fstat()`.

Comment: Now i replace some of things might you observe it. using fstat() instead of fseek that i don't get it. Is there any specific reason to use fstat().

Comment: @ravibhuva9955: Kinda. I didn't count it as a crashbug, because it takes a lot of effort to mess up so badly that casting the return value of `malloc()` causes a bug. It is *possible*, however, given the right (read: wrong) circumstances: 1. Forget to include <stdlib.h>. 2. Compile with little warnings. 3. Have a platform where `sizeof(int)!=sizeof(void*)`. 4. Use more than 4 gigabytes (2 to the power of (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT) of memory.

Comment: @EOF - 1. stdlib.h is already there. 2. which compile warnings. 3&4. what are you try to explain me i don't get it.

Comment: @ravibhuva9955 On `fstat()`: If you use `mmap()`, you need to provide a size argument (the file size). The whole point of `mmap()` is that you *don't* first iterate through the whole file, character by character. So you just ask the file system nicely, and you get the file size. Much less fuss. On casting `malloc()`: There are about a bazillion topics on SE for that. But consider this: By default, an undeclared function returns an `int`. The function calling `malloc()` may interpret its return value as an `int` (truncating the `void *` it really returns), and then extend it again.

Comment: 1st point is very good. Where in 2nd point when we use calloc in place of malloc at that time same scenario is produced due to type casting. So is there any solution?

Comment: @ravibhuva9955: Just declare `char *data` and assign with `data = calloc(1,size)`. No cast is needed in C (unlike C++).

Comment: Unable to use ./yourfile.c < sample.txt

Comment: You need to compile your c code and then you can execute it as displayed above.

Comment: @EOF: Kinda. So in that case malloc is also work without type casting.